# EC2 - Huge latency in saving streaming data to local file

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, file-io

I've written some python code to receive streaming tick trading data from an API (TWS API of Interactive Brokers using IB Gateway) and append data to file in the local machine. On a daily basis, the amount of data is roughly no more than 1GB. In addition, the 1GB of steaming data per day is composed by several millions of read/write operations for a few 100s of bytes each.

When I run the code in my local machine, the latency between the timestamp associated with the received tick data and when the data is appended to file is in the order of 0.5 to 2 seconds. However, when I run the same code in an EC2 instance, the latency explodes to minutes or hours.

At 4:30 UTC the markets open. The first chart shows that the latency is not due to RAM, CPU and presumedly IOPS. Volume type is gp2 with 100 IOPS for t2.micro and 900 IOPS for m5.large.

How to find what's causing the huge latency?

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: A 3rd chart showing the metrics in the same 10 minute time frame from the 1st chart may be helpful to review. Why no disk r/w metrics? Can you chart RAM usage?  Just curious re Ram but also good to check.

Comment: I've added new charts with metrics. Do EBS Bytes and IO balance % look suspicious?

Comment: In addition, the 1GB of steaming data per day is composed by several millions of read/write operations for a few 100s of bytes each.

Comment: Take a look at the VolumeIdleTime and  VolumeThroughputPercentage stats graphs on the EBS volumes.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I've added two pics with EBS volume stats for the m5.large instance with 900 IOPS

Comment: It certainly looks like you are hammering that EBS volume pretty mercilessly.  It bears asking... these are not volumes recently created from EBS snapshots are they?  If so, you need to warm them up or your performance will not be pretty until you do.

Comment: I confirm that volumes are not created from EBS snapshots. Would you be able in indicate possible solution (e.g. higher IOPS, i3 instances, higher network performance, use io1 SSD)? I'm just surprised that an m5.large instance can't handle to write 1GB of data per day, maybe something wrong with the settings?